# Exam package: add title only for \titledquestion

Tags: exam

I wanted to use the `exam` package and have titled and non-titled questions in the following format:

```
\question Which sentence is true?
```

should give

---

```
**Question 1:**                  [1] (<-- in a box on the right margin)  
Which sentence is true?
```

---

But the following

```
\titledquestion{Resolution}
\begin{parts}
\part[1] What is up?
\part[1] What is going on?
\end{parts}
```

should give

---

```
**Question 2:** Resolution [6 points total] <-- next to resolution

(a) What is up?                                  [3](@box right margin)
(b) What is going on?                            [3](@box right margin)
```

---

Here's my minimum-almost-working example, but I have the problem, that the format of the `question` and the format of the `titledquestion` are the same thing, so I'd like to format the titles separately, and ideally have the point for non-titled questions also as box in the right margin.

---

```
\documentclass[addpoints,12pt]{exam}
\usepackage{amssymb}

% to have the points on the right margin
\pointsinrightmargin

% make boxes/brackets around the points instead of parantheses
\boxedpoints

%%%%%%% format the question header

\qformat{
 \textbf{Question \thequestion:}
 \textit{\thequestiontitle}
 [\totalpoints~\points]\hfill
 \vrule depth 0.75em width 0pt
}

% get rid of extra indentation after the start of a question

\renewcommand{\questionshook}{%
 \setlength{\leftmargin}{0 pt}%
 \setlength{\labelwidth}{-\labelsep}%
}

%%%%%% change the check-box symbols

\checkboxchar{$\Box$}
\checkedchar{$\blacksquare$}
\begin{document}


\begin{questions}

\question[1] Which of these is true
\begin{checkboxes} 
\choice 1=1
\choice 2=1
\choice 3=1
\end{checkboxes} 

\titledquestion{Resolution}
Here's the intro ...
\begin{parts}
\part[3] What's up?
\part[3] What's going on?
\end{parts}

\end{questions}

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 2):

If a question has no title, the exam class sets the title to the current question label. The following code tests if the title is the current label and only print the title if it is different from the label:

```
\documentclass[addpoints,12pt]{exam}
\usepackage{amssymb}

% to have the points on the right margin
\pointsinrightmargin

% make boxes/brackets around the points instead of parantheses
\boxedpoints

%%%%%%% format the question header
\makeatletter
\qformat{%
 \textbf{Question \thequestion:}%
 \if\thequestiontitle\csname p@question\endcsname
                           \csname thequestion\endcsname
 \else%
 \textit{\space\thequestiontitle}
 \fi%
 \hfill%[\totalpoints~\points]
\rlap{%
%\hskip-\@totalleftmargin
%                  \hskip\textwidth
                  \hskip\@rightmargin
                  \hskip-\rightpointsmargin
                  \llap{\point@block}%
            }%
% \vrule depth 0.75em width 0pt
}
\makeatother
% get rid of extra indentation after the start of a question

\renewcommand{\questionshook}{%
 \setlength{\leftmargin}{0 pt}%
 \setlength{\labelwidth}{-\labelsep}%
}

%%%%%% change the check-box symbols

\checkboxchar{$\Box$}
\checkedchar{$\blacksquare$}
\begin{document}


\begin{questions}

\question[1] Which of these is true
\begin{checkboxes} 
\choice 1=1
\choice 2=1
\choice 3=1
\end{checkboxes} 

\titledquestion{Resolution}[5]
Here's the intro ...
\begin{parts}
\part[3] What's up?
\part[3] What's going on?
\end{parts}

\end{questions}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: great, thanks. do you also happen to know how to have the points of a single question appear as box on the right margin (just like for the `part`s)?

Comment: @JohnSmith Sorry, I don't understand this new question

Comment: it's in the original explanation: for the non-titled question, the points should also be typeset in a box on the right margin, not just as `[1 point]`in brackets, but like the boxed digits "3" in the image you attached.

Comment: @JohnSmith Ah, I think I understand. Let my try something

Comment: @JohnSmith Look now?

Comment: Thanks a lot! I will accept it as correct answer in a moment, just one more question: in your original answer, a new problem occurred: if I get rid of the `[5]` after `{Resolution}` which shouldn't be there, then the writing out of the points changes to the right sum, but the "points" becomes singular, so it was `[11 points]` (right plural, but wrong number because there should be 6 points), now it's `[6 point]` right number but wrong singular. Any idea where that comes from? Similar issue is in your current answer. Removing the `[5]` not states 1 point for question 5, which should be 6.

Comment: ok, there is a deeper issue, if I for example put the first question to 10 points, this will affect the point count in the second question